# How can I switch my primary display used in Windows' Projection Mode?

Tags: windows-7, external-display

Windows 7 and Vista has a feature called Projection Mode triggered from Windows key + P.

My problem is that the primary display (connected via DVI-D) is identified as the projector (and has been assigned the number 2 even though I have selected it to be the primary monitor) and that the projector is identified as the screen (and assigned number 1).

How can I switch these around so that the projector is properly identified as the projector and the screen as the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only way to do it in a way that is remembered by the OS for more than a sessions is by using adapters to fit the cables into what the graphic card insists is the first port.

Answer (score 1):

On my Thinkpad T42 my DVI output didn't work while connected docked in my docking station. What helped to use it properly was to boot with it connected. Maybe this will help you out as well:

1. Shutdown your Windows (power off)
2. Plug in your DVI screen
3. Boot (your DVI should display as your only and primary screen)
4. Plug in your projector after Windows booted properly

Your projector should now apper as secondary display when select "extended view" for the projector to get a signal as well.

Comment: Hm. No good. The ordering is still wrong.

Answer (score -1):

#### How to set a monitor as the primary display - Windows 7

1. Right-Click on an *empty space* on the *desktop*
2. Click on **Screen Resolution**
3. Click on **Identify**

   - Notice the *number* displayed on the device you want as your primary display
4. Click on the **Display** *drop-down menu*
5. Select the device that you want to be your primary display
6. Check the `Make this my main display` box
7. Click on **OK**

*Note: Steps are in detail for both the experienced and non-experienced.*

Comment: As I say, the monitor has already been set as the primary monitor. What Windows gets wrong is which of the monitors is the projector.